# How to show a mobile preview in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I have a desktop website, and I want to show a mobile preview of the website (just a popup screen, no new windows or something).
All elements on the site are position absolute, so everything needs to be scaled I think.
What is the best way to do this?
I thought it could be done by setting a viewport, but as far as I know, it's not possible to set a viewport on just 1 div (which is kind of logical). So another solution needs to be found.

Comment: `"Ajax"`, `css media queries`....

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by « *mobile preview of the website* ».

My first thought is that the difference between mobile and desktop is probably governed by media queries — in which you could include an iframe to the same URL, making sure that the media queries are of the form `width`, not `device-width`.

Elsewhere you mention that « *everything needs to be scaled* » which implies that you just want a reduced view. In this case you could repeat the iframe trick, and apply a `transform: scale( 0.5, 0.5 )`. This would reduced the size of the rendered output.